# Can I reset a VNC connection to a DomU?

Tags: xen, vnc

VNC to my DomU VMs works great. The only problem is that I can only have one vnc client at a time connected, and if someone leaves a session logged in, or if I am disconnected suddenly, I have to wait for it to time out before I can connect again. Is it possible to reset a vnc connection from the command line in Dom0 so I can reconnect immediately? Note that I'm using the built-in vnc in Xen 4.0, not vncserver running in dom0.

Answer (score 0):

The VNC gets connected to a X-server in the DomU. Perhaps you can kill the session by terminating or restarting that X-server.

Comment: This is just not true for builtin vnc.